# How do I find a closed form expression for a sum

Tags: combinatorics, summation, closed-form

If $k$ and $n$ are positive integers, how do I give a simple closed form
expression for the sum
$\sum_{a_1+···+a_k=n} {n \choose a_1,...,a_k}$

I'm not sure the process of finding a closed form expression and I think understanding this general case will help for explicit questions like ${9 \choose a, b, c}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By the multinomial theorem, the sum in question evaluates to $(1 + 1 + \cdots + 1)^n = k^n$. For $k = 2$ this reduces to the famous binomial identity $\sum_a \binom n a = 2^n$.

More explicitly: For $k = 2$ we get $\sum_a \binom n a = \sum_a \binom n a 1^a 1^{n-a} = (1+1)^n = 2^n$. And for $k = 3$ we get $\sum_{a_1+a_2+a_3 = n} \binom {n} {a_1,a_2,a_3}1^{a_1} 1^{a_2} 1^{a_3} = (1+1+1)^n = 3^n$.

Comment: so does that mean the closed form of  i.e. $\sum_{a+b+c=7} {7 \choose a, b, c}$ is $(1+...+1)^7$ ?

Comment: Yes, with $3$ $1$'s. So $3^7$.